# AndroidManifest file with different package name for china for different flavor.

Tags: android

I am releasing the build for china market and we all know that they don't support Playstore. Henceforth we have decided to release in china stores.

One of the china store has requirement to have the package name in manifest file 
must contain the application name. But right now our Main manifest file package name does not contain the application name.

So we created new Manifest file for china flavor with only package name change but Android studio expects the User Permission and Activity declarations in this china manifest file.

Can we create the manifest with only package name changes? All the other permissions and declaration must e taken from Main Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify package name in gradle for each flavor. Use the `applicationId` parameter

```
buildTypes {

    forChina {
        applicationId my.domain.appName.chinasuffix
    }

    notForChina {
        applicationId my.domain.appName.other
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. ApplicationId is different from package name in manifest file. I have done this, but i need package name different for China and other country.